# Missing information in the Great Worm Cavern in the Storm King's Thunder adventure

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, content-identification, storm-kings-thunder

On page 88 of the *Storm King's Thunder* adventure, under the [**Great Worm Cavern**](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/skt/the-savage-frontier#GreatWormCavern) heading, in the [**Altar**](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/skt/the-savage-frontier#Altar) section, the end of the second paragraph reads:

> The couatl knows that Wormblod is away, searching for a missing concubine named If the characters present proof of Wormblod's death as offering to the altar, see "Development."

There seems to be some content missing after the word 'named'!
And, I'm not sure where the 'Development' section resolves to.

Anyone have any ideas as to what content is supposed to be there?
Yes, I could make something up, but would like to know where Wormblod is!

Comment: Thanks, Thomas. It is indeed from the 5e D&D campaign.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### The information about this development is part of the "Treasure" section

It is probably an editing mistake; it is missing from [the book's errata](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/SKT-Errata.pdf), and D&D Beyond is not updated either. The second paragraph under the [Treasure](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/skt/the-savage-frontier#Treasure3) section describes the development of the situation:

> If the characters slay Wormblod and bring proof of his demise, the couatl emerges from the altar and bestows on each of them a *charm of restoration* (see the “Supernatural Gifts” section in chapter 7 of the *Dungeon Master’s Guide*). The couatl then returns to the altar and makes no further attempt to communicate with them.

### The missing name

So, for the name of the missing concubine, I looked into the [*Storm King's Thunder* errata](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/SKT-Errata.pdf), and couldn't find the missing word. However, in chapter 4 of the adventure, you can discover the missing name. The description of [area 4](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/skt/the-chosen-path#4GiantDoors) of the Eye of the All-Father states:

> Wormblod and his barbarians have come to the Eye of the All-Father to find a missing member of their tribe (see area 9A).

And the description of the [mentioned area](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/skt/the-chosen-path#9ALarder) states the character's name:

> The third [cocoon] contains a living Uthgardt barbarian of the Great Worm tribe named **Noori** [...]

Comment: Do we have any other indication that Noori is a concubine? Or do you reckon that “concubine” is a mistake?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Nothing in her description explicitly use the word concubine, but she fits the description of a missing person that Wormblod is looking for.

Comment: I didn't make the connection that the concubine is Noori in area 9A. But that now makes sense. Thank you both - appreciate the help.

Comment: It would help to include the name in non-spoiler text, so those who want to know the name but don’t want spoilers can see it. They’ll have to take your word for it, but votes from those who don’t mine spoilers should be quite sufficient to give them confidence.

Answer (score 5):

#### The “Development” header is missing, the content is under “Treasure”.

Just below the passage you quote, we see the “Treasure” section, which contains the info you seek:

> #### Treasure
>
> The remorhaz lair can be explored and plundered if the creatures are killed. The area is a 20-foot-diameter oval chamber with walls of glazed ice. Scattered on the floor are three 500 gp gemstones, fifteen 100 gp gemstones, and one magic item determined by rolling on Magic Item Table C in chapter 7 of the Dungeon Master’s Guide.
>
> #### [“Development” header should be right here but isn’t]
>
> *If the characters slay Wormblod and bring proof of his demise, the couatl emerges from the altar and bestows on each of them a charm of restoration (see the “Supernatural Gifts” section in chapter 7 of the Dungeon Master’s Guide). The couatl then returns to the altar and makes no further attempt to communicate with them.*

The section in the question says “if the characters present proof of Wormblod's death as offering to the altar, see ‘Development’”, and the italicized passage above tells what happens if you present proof of Wormblod’s death to the altar.

As for the concubine, the quote given in the question is the only occurrence of the word “concubine” in the entire adventure, so I’m not sure we can find that one. Kuerten postulates in [their answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/192072/62294) a possible candidate, but descriptions of that person do not seem to line up with “concubine”.

Comment: Hm. I read that the 'remorhaz lair' is in reference to the Great Worm Cavern itself. Under the **Ancient Relic** heading, the remorhaz appear if the gong is struck.

The Development heading missing makes sense.

Comment: "Kuerten postulates in their answer a possible candidate, but descriptions of that person do not seem to line up with “concubine”." Why not? Just because she's a badass barbarian chick doesn't mean that she can't also be the lower-status/unofficial wife of a barbarian chieftain. That she's willing to fight to the death to try to avenge his death certain does suggest a romantic attachment.